# How to move elements together in generated RTF by Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using Jasper Reports for generating RTF file. Version 6.7.

I have two text fields. In generated RTF I can select them and they look like the following:
[image]

If I move one text field by mouse, the second does not move:
[image]

*Is it possible to set up Jasper Reports element to it's position depends on the position of the other element? I am saying about activity in **generated RTF**, not in Jasper Studio.*

For example, when I move *Text Field 1* to the right, *Text Field 2* is moved to the right automatically:
[image]

Comment: `Is it possible to set up Jasper Reports element to it's position depends on the position of the other element?` - Yes, for vertical position, but not for horizontal

Comment: @AlexK, ok, what configuration is responsible for dependence of vertical position? I mean how the elements should be configured to one element depends on the other?